# Missing access log for virtual host on Plesk

Tags: apache-http-server, logging, virtual-host, plesk

For some reason i don't understand, after creating a new virtual host / domain in Plesk a few months back, i cannot seem to find the access log.

I noticed this when running

```
/usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/statistics
```

The host in question is being scanned

```
Main HTML page is 'awstats.<hostname_masked>-http.html'.
Create/Update database for config "/opt/psa/etc/awstats/awstats.<hostname_masked>.com-https.conf" by AWStats version 6.95 (build 1.943)
From data in log file "-"...
Phase 1 : First bypass old records, searching new record...
Searching new records from beginning of log file...
Jumped lines in file: 0
Parsed lines in file: 0
 Found 0 dropped records,
 Found 0 corrupted records,
 Found 0 old records,
 Found 0 new qualified records.
```

So basically no access logs have been parsed/found. I then went on to check if i could find the log myself.

I looked in

```
/var/www/vhosts/<hostname_masked>.com/statistics/logs
```

but all i find is

```
error_log
```

Does anybody know what is wrong here and perhaps how i could fix this?

Note: in the

```
<hostname_masked>.com/conf/
```

folder i keep a custom vhost.conf file, which however contains only some rewrite conditions plus a directory statement that contains php_admin_flag and php_admin_value settings. None of them are related to logging though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find access log data in /var/log/apache2/

It was not ordered correctly and it was zipped up due to logration features.

In any case, adding this line to my vhost.conf in /var/www/vhosts//conf/

```
CustomLog /var/www/vhosts/<hostname_masked>/statistics/logs/ combined
```

turned out to solve the logging issue for this specific VirtualHost.

Answer (score 2):

If no customizations applied, access_log should be exactly in `/var/www/vhosts/<hostname_masked>.com/statistics/logs`

I would try to check the following

1. You really have visitors to the site
2. Check that you have this line in `/var/www/vhosts/<hostname_masked>.com/last_httpd.include`:

   ErrorLog  "/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/statistics/logs/error_log"
3. Check content of `/var/log/httpd/access_log`
4. Check logrotation policy (available in Plesk UI) and increase period / size to rotate

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The site has visitors, definitely - its a shop and many orders have come in. I cannot find a last_httpd.include. The error log works just fine. Your hint for /var/log/httpd/access_log was pretty good as i was able to find access logs in /var/log/apache2/ but there are multiple tar.gz archives in there and its quite a mess. Using |grep i was able to find <hostname_masked> in what cat * had returned in that folder, but i have no idea how to get all the data from the last few months. I wonder why Plesk is not saving those logs to the actual vhosts log dir :(

Comment: May be you need to call support. Normally access_log should be in vhost directory.

Comment: For my Plesk 12 I found the log file from checking the `/var/www/vhosts/<hostname_masked>.com/conf/httpd.conf` which pointed at `/var/www/vhosts/system/<hostname_masked>/logs/error_log`